# Ignore some controls from Form.ValidateChildren() method

Tags: c#, validation

I have a form that gets validated on save button by `ValidateChildren` method.

`Id` field also has a `validating` and a `validated` to allow quick re-loading of a (different) document from the database.

The actual **problem** is when I submit the form: the `IdText` control **must not** get **validated** at all, else the model will be reloaded. Solutions?

```
private void IdText_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int n = 0;
        var isNumeric = int.TryParse(IdText.Text, out n);
        if (!isNumeric)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            throw new Exception("Valore inserito non valido");
            return;
        }
        dxErrorProvider.SetError(IdText, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Errore", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        return;
    }

}

private void IdText_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int n = 0;
        var isNumeric = int.TryParse(IdText.Text, out n);

        if (!isNumeric) throw new Exception("Valore inserito non valido");
        model = Registrazione.Manager.GetRegistrazione(n);

        if (model == null) throw new Exception("Registrazione con id " + n + " non trovata.");
        model.PropertyChanged += OnModelPropertyChanged;
        BindMovimentiEventHandlers(null, null);
        CaricamentoRegistrazione_Load(sender, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Errore", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error); return;
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks like the code assumes that the Validated event only fires when the Text property changed.  That is not accurate.  You'll need a variable that stores the active id so that you can tell whether you actually need to do anything drastic.

Comment: Would you give me more details about your pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I found that overriding the `ValidateChildren` was one of the possible solutions to achieve what I really wanted, and then creating a method to catch the `Validating` event handlers of each control, however, I am aware of the reflection and its insecurities. Code:

```
public override bool ValidateChildren()
        {
            bool allValid = true;
            foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
            {
                if (control.Name == "Id")
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (!control.IsValid())
                {
                    allValid = false;
                }
            }
            return allValid;
        }

public static bool IsValid(this Control controlToValidate)
        {
            Debug.Assert(controlToValidate != null, "Control to validate is null");

            Type t = typeof(Control);


            MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("NotifyValidating", BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod);

            Debug.Assert(mi != null, "Could not get method information.");

            return !((Boolean)mi.Invoke(controlToValidate, null));

        }
```